# Why Akka Http Client Throws an Exception on Any Other from Successful Response Status?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using Akka Http (v. 10.1.10) to create a client with proxy. 
Each time the response is any other than successful, I get an error instead of a proper response entity:

```
akka.http.impl.engine.client.ProxyConnectionFailedException: The HTTP(S) proxy rejected to open a connection to hahahahahhahaahahhahaadsfsd.com:80 with status code: 503 Service Unavailable
    at akka.http.impl.engine.client.HttpsProxyGraphStage$$anon$1$$anon$4.onPush(HttpsProxyGraphStage.scala:143)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:523)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:409)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:606)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:485)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:581)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:749)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:764)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:671)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

In the Akka Http core code, I found that it is the implementation of the handler for proxy that forces the error on purpose if the response is any other than successful:

```
          case Connecting =>
            val proxyResponse = grab(bytesIn)
            parser.parseBytes(proxyResponse) match {
              case NeedMoreData =>
                pull(bytesIn)
              case ResponseStart(_: StatusCodes.Success, _, _, _, _) =>
                var pushed = false
                val parseResult = parser.onPull()
                require(parseResult == ParserOutput.MessageEnd, s"parseResult should be MessageEnd but was $parseResult")
                parser.onPull() match {
                  // NeedMoreData is what we emit in overridden `parseMessage` in case input.size == offset
                  case NeedMoreData =>
                  case RemainingBytes(bytes) =>
                    push(sslOut, bytes) // parser already read more than expected, forward that data directly
                    pushed = true
                  case other =>
                    throw new IllegalStateException(s"unexpected element of type ${other.getClass}")
                }
                parser.onUpstreamFinish()

                log.debug(s"HTTP(S) proxy connection to {}:{} established. Now forwarding data.", targetHostName, targetPort)

                state = Connected
                if (isAvailable(bytesOut)) pull(sslIn)
                if (isAvailable(sslOut)) pull(bytesIn)
              case ResponseStart(statusCode, _, _, _, _) =>
                failStage(new ProxyConnectionFailedException(s"The HTTP(S) proxy rejected to open a connection to $targetHostName:$targetPort with status code: $statusCode"))
              case other =>
                throw new IllegalStateException(s"unexpected element of type $other")
            }
```

I am wondering what is the reason for such implementation, if someone knows? And how to work it around to get a response entity instead of the error when response from the server is not successful?

Comment: That code refers to the response of the proxy not to the response of the server you sent the response to. If you go through an HTTPS proxy, the client will create an http connection to the proxy first using the `CONNECT` method. If the proxy returns a successful status code, it has established a tunnel to the target host and the client can go on creating an HTTPS connections across the tunnel. If the status code is unsuccessful, there's nothing that could be done, it's like a TCP connection failing.

Comment: Hi @jrudolph! Thank you for the response. It explains the implementation. If you put it as an answer, I could accept  it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try recover function to capture and return response entity you want.

```
    Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(
      uri = url
    )).map(response => {
      response
    }) recover {
      case e: Exception => {
        e.printStackTrace()
        // anything you want to return
        HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am afraid that this approach is not what I am looking for :( I need the original status code and and error message. The only way to get it with catch -- is to do parsing of the ProxyConnectionFailedException. And it looks ugly as hell. I wonder if there is a way to pass or configure the handler somewhere.

Comment: extract response.status.intValue() . it will tell you the status code. 200/503

Comment: I wish I could... There is no response though, the request fails if the proxy answers with any other code than successful